# initing a pytest fixture with a parameter

Tags: python, pytest

I have a fixture that creates an object I use in many tests.
This Object has a property - `priority` (1 - 10)

Now, there are a lot of tests that need to "know" the priority of the object (in order to test various logic paths)

So I could have 10 different fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture
def object_priority_1():
    return MyObj(priority=1)
@pytest.fixture
def object_priority_2():
    return MyObj(priority=2)
//....
@pytest.fixture
def object_priority_10():
    return MyObj(priority=10)
```

But it seems off... I'm sure there is a way to deliver an external param to a fixture each time - I just couldn't find it

**Edit:**
To clarify - I would have wanted something in the area of:

```
@pytest.fixture
    def my_object(<priority as an external param>):
        return MyObj(priority)
```

And then the test would be something like:

```
def test_foo(my_object(1), my_object(6)):
//...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [py.test: Pass a parameter to a fixture function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/py-test-pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do :

```
@pytest.fixture
def my_object(priority):
    return MyObj(priority)    

def test_foo(my_object):
    obj_1 = my_object(1)
    assert something # 1
    obj_2 = my_object(2)
    assert something # 2
```

I come with this idea, then I found this Q&A :

[py.test: Pass a parameter to a fixture function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/py-test-pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function)

I think your question maybe consider a duplicate if your problem is solved.

Comment: I tried this particular syntax earlier and didn't quite work, it errored out saying there fixture `priority` couldn't be found. The solution in the link you provided does work though.

Comment: Is an object (function) defined with an parameters named priority?

Comment: Not with that specific variable name. I got it working when I used the variable name `request`, but didn't work when i replaced the variable with the one i actually wanted to use (`filename`). I'm going to try it again in case it was user error. You can see the code I'm refering to [here](https://github.com/vmuriart/sqlparse/blob/85349e68592964e66e5dfe7e48e9f76cb93d48fd/tests/conftest.py#L32)

Comment: `fixture 'priority' not found
available fixtures: tmpdir_factory, pytestconfig, filepath, cache, recwarn, monkeypatch, record_xml_property, capfd, load_file, capsys, tmpdir
        use 'py.test --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.` same error as before

Comment: I gave a look at the code, I am not exactly sure I understand what you are trying to do... Please try the code as is and see if it allow to what it is suppose to do which is passing a parameter to an object from a test... You can mock the MyObj with a simple print function for instance... I am not sure it the right place to resolve your issue as I feel I would need much more inside on what you are doing and we are not supposed to use comment for this purpose...

Comment: No worries. My code is working using the solution provided on your link. I meant my initial comment as an FYI for anyone else that may have having similar issues as I did. It's still very likely it might be a mistake on my side though. Thanks for following up though :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this, it will return run your fixture with each of those params:

```
@pytest.fixture(
    params=[
        "param1",
        "param2",
        "param3",
        "param4",
        "param5",
        "param6",
    ]
)
def fixture_with_params(request):
    return request.param
```