# pytest fixture with parametrization from another fixture

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I am using pytest and would like to invoke a test function for a number of objects returned by a server, and for a number of servers.

The servers are defined in a YAML file and those definitions are provided as parametrization to a fixture "server_connection" that returns a Connection object for a single server. Due to the parametrization, it causes the test function to be invoked once for each server.

I am able to do this with a loop in the test function: There is a second fixture "server_objects" that takes a "server_connection" fixture as input and returns a list of server objects. The pytest test function then takes that second fixture and executes the actual test in a loop through the server objects.

Here is that code:

```
import pytest

SD_LIST = ... # read list of server definitions from YAML file

@pytest.fixture(
    params=SD_LIST,
    scope='module'
)
def server_connection(request):
    server_definition = request.param
    return Connection(server_definition.url, ...)

@pytest.fixture(
    scope='module'
)
def server_objects(request, server_connection):
    return server_connection.get_objects()

def test_object_foo(server_objects):
    for server_object in server_objects:
        # Perform test for a single server object:
        assert server_object == 'foo'
```

However, the disadvantage is of course that a test failure causes the entire test function to end.

What I want to happen instead is that the test function is invoked for each single server object, so that a test failure for one object does not prevent the tests on the other objects. Ideally, I'd like to have a fixture that provides a single server object, that I can pass to the test function:

```
...

@pytest.fixture(
    scope='module'
)
def server_object(request, server_connection):
    server_objects = server_connection.get_objects()
    # TBD: Some magic to parametrize this fixture with server_objects

def test_object_foo(server_object):
    # Perform test for a single server object:
    assert server_object == 'foo'
```

I have read through all pytest docs regarding fixtures but did not find a way to do this.

I know about pytest hooks and have used e.g. pytest_generate_tests() before, but I did not find a way how pytest_generate_tests() can access the values of other fixtures.

Any ideas?

Update: Let me add that I also did search SO for this, but did not find an answer. I specifically looked at:

- [pytest fixture of fixtures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35777854/1424462)
- [How to parametrize a Pytest fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42228895/1424462)
- [py.test: Pass a parameter to a fixture function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18011902/1424462)
- [initing a pytest fixture with a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32275347/1424462)

Comment: I haven't analyzed your problem too thoroughly, but maybe you can make it work using `pytest_generate_tests`, to dynamically parametrize your test with the individual `server_object`s? https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example