# indirect=True vs indirect=False in @pytest.mark.parametrize()?

Tags: python, testing, pytest, parameterized-unit-test, parameterized-tests

I just want to understand what it means or what happens if I set indirect parameter to `True` or `False` in the `pytest.mark.parametrize`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function/33879151#33879151 It is used to pass a parameter to a fixture

Answer (score 49, accepted):

With `indirect=True` you can parametrize your fixture, `False` - default value. Example:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_name(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.mark.parametrize('fixture_name', ['foo', 'bar'], indirect=True)
def test_indirect(fixture_name):
    assert fixture_name == 'baz'
```

So this example generates two tests. First one gets from `fixture_name` value **foo**, because this fixture for this test runs with parametization. Second test gets **bar** value. And each tests will fail, because of assert checking for **baz**.

Comment: indirect=True ensures you still execute the fixture body when you use parametrize on a test.

Comment: So `indirect` is a way to parametrize fixtures. And the main difference compared to parametrize the fixture using `pytest.fixture(params=[...])` is that the fixture can be parametrized only for the specific test function (otherwise it always parametrize for all test functions that use the fixture) ?

Comment: How would you assert the returns in this case?

Comment: I just discovered that it's necessary that the fixture's argument (that will accept the parameter) is called `request`. Other names will not work, and pytest will complain that that other-named fixture does not exist. pytest 6.2.2

Comment: how do you use named parameters where `['foo', 'bar']` is?

Answer (score 3):

For example, `indirect=False` is set to [@pytest.mark.parametrize()](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.Metafunc.parametrize) as shown below. *Actually, by default, `indirect=False` is set to `@pytest.mark.parametrize()` implicitly so you don't need to set `indirect=False` to it explicitly:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def fruits(request):
    return f'fruits {request.param}'

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "fruits", 
    ("Apple", "Orange", "Banana"), 
    indirect=False # Here
)
def test(fruits):
    print(fruits)
    assert True
```

Then, `Apple`, `Orange` and `Banana` are passed to `test()` directly as shown below. *Actually, `fruits()` fixture is not run:

```
$ pytest -q -rP
...                              [100%]
=============== PASSES ================ 
_____________ test[Apple] _____________ 
-------- Captured stdout call --------- 
Apple
____________ test[Orange] _____________ 
-------- Captured stdout call --------- 
Orange
____________ test[Banana] _____________ 
-------- Captured stdout call --------- 
Banana
3 passed in 0.10s
```

Now, `indirect=True` is set to `@pytest.mark.parametrize()` as shown below:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def fruits(request):
    return f'fruits {request.param}'

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "fruits", 
    ("Apple", "Orange", "Banana"), 
    indirect=True # Here
)
def test(fruits):
    print(fruits)
    assert True
```

Then, `Apple`, `Orange` and `Banana` are passed to `test()` indirectly through `fruits()` fixture as shown below. *Both `test()` and `fruits()` fixture are run:

```
$ pytest -q -rP
...                              [100%]
=============== PASSES ================ 
_____________ test[Apple] _____________ 
-------- Captured stdout call --------- 
fruits Apple
____________ test[Orange] _____________ 
-------- Captured stdout call --------- 
fruits Orange
____________ test[Banana] _____________ 
-------- Captured stdout call --------- 
fruits Banana
3 passed in 0.10s
```