# Pytest and pytest-django: How can I run each test (complete with setup and teardown) multiple times with different contexts?

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I am setting up the test platform for a multi-tenant system.

For each written test, I want to create a test for each tenant and wrap the entire test run to change the database connexion and some thread local variable before the test without breaking the database teardown where it flushes.

During my trial-and-error process, I've resorted to climbing higher and higher in the pytest hook chain: I started with `pytest_generate_tests` to create a test for each tenant with an associated fixture, but the teardown failed, I've ended up at the following idea:

```
def pytest_runtestloop(session):
    for tenant in range(settings.TENANTS.keys()):
        with set_current_tenant(tenant):
            with environ({'DJANGO_CONFIGURATION': f'Test{tenant.capitalize()}Config'}):
                session.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("main").pytest_runtestloop(session)

    return True
```

Although this does not work (since `django-configurations` loads the settings during the earlier `pytest_load_initial_conftests` phase), this example should give an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

The big roadblock: The `default` database connection needs to point to the current tenant's database before any fixtures are loaded and after `flush` is ran.

I have disabled `pytest-django`'s default session fixture mechanism and plan on using a external database for tests :

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_setup():
    pass
```

I could have a wrapper python script that calls `pytest` multiple times with the right config, but I would lose a lot of nice tooling.

Comment: Have you looked into parameterized fixture?

Comment: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/proposals/parametrize_with_fixtures.html

You can parametrize fixture over different types of sessions and all tests will run across all db sessions.

Comment: @SilentGuy hi, I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I have indeed already looked into this, but it is unfortunately only a proposal, and nothing is implemented yet. I have not had a strong enough intensive to actually do a PR myself for now.

Comment: My bad. I shared the wrong link. You can parametrize fixture by using indirect parametrization. More info here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments . A relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44568273/2312300https://stackoverflow.com/a/44568273/2312300

Comment: @SilentGuy thanks for your enthusiasic help, but my issue has to do with parametrizing a much earlier stage of pytest's run, and I don't believe parameterized fixtures can help me there.

Comment: You can parametrize test at test collection using pytest_generate_tests(metafunc) default fixture.
Source: https://pytest.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.3/example/parametrize.html