# Pytests: getting error function uses no argument error

Tags: python, pytest, parametrized-testing, parametrize, parameterized-constructor

I have following code:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_path_functions(mocker, file_exists=True, file_size=10):
    mock_obj = mock.Mock()
    mock_obj.st_size = file_size
    mocker.patch("os.path.exists", return_value=file_exists)
    mocker.patch("os.stat", return_value=mock_obj)
 
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("mock_path_functions")
@ytest.mark.parametrize("file_exists,file_size", [(False, 0)])
def test_subscrition_handle_from_file_when_file_is_not_present():
    assert subscrition_handle_from_file("some path") == None
```

However I'm getting following error:

`In test_subscrition_handle_from_file_when_file_is_not_present: function uses no argument 'file_exists'`

How I can specify parameters to `mock_path_function()`?

Comment: You need to swap the position of your decorators.!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parametrize a Pytest fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228895/how-to-parametrize-a-pytest-fixture)

Comment: Thanks, changed position of arguments but same result

Comment: I checked "How to Parametrize" SF post, but I haven't found a solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to pass your arguments into your test function, like

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("mock_path_functions")
@ytest.mark.parametrize("file_exists,file_size", [(False, 0)])
def test_subscrition_handle_from_file_when_file_is_not_present(
    file_exists, file_size
):
    assert subscrition_handle_from_file("some path") == None
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below with [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [pytest-factoryboy](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-factoryboy) in Django:

> Failed: In test_user_instance: function uses no argument 'email'

Because I did not put `email` argument to `test_user_instance()` even though I set `email` to [@pytest.mark.parametrize()](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/how-to/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions) as shown below:

```py
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "username, email", # Here
    [
        ("John", "test1@test1.com"),
        ("David", "test2@test2.com")
    ]
)
def test_user_instance(
    db, user_factory, username, # email # Here
):
    user_factory(
        username=username,
        # email=email
    )

    item = User.objects.all().count()
    assert item == True
```

So, I put `email` argument to `test_user_instance()` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "username, email",
    [
        ("John", "test1@test1.com"),
        ("David", "test2@test2.com")
    ]
)
def test_user_instance(
    db, user_factory, username, email # Here
):
    user_factory(
        username=username,
        email=email
    )

    item = User.objects.all().count()
    assert item == True
```