# how to test multiple json responses with requests-mock

Tags: python, pytest, requests-mock

I'm creating some unit tests using the pytest module and requests-mock for mocking the Response object for requests. I have the following pytest fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def mock_response(requests_mock):
    test_url = "https://dummy/"
    test_json = [{"Name": "TheName"}, {"Name": "TheOtherName"}]
    requests_mock.get(test_url, json=test_json, status_code=200)
    resp = requests.get(test_url)
    return resp
```

and the following unit test

```
def test_get_product_list(mocker, mock_response):
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as m:
        ret_val = mock_response
        mocker.patch("path_to_function.function_with_request",
                 return_value=ret_val)
        val = function_with_request(123)
        assert val == ["TheName", "TheOtherName"]
```

The `function_with_request` makes an API call and then parses the `Response` to make a list of values with the `Name` key

I want to run this test with a few different values for `test_json`. I looked into parameterized fixtures, but none of the examples I saw seemed to match what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42228895/11246056

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question's a bit old but I encountered this issue because I completely misread the requests-mock docs. (facepalm) While the original Q might be related to fixtures, which is solvable with parametrizing it as one commented noted, my answer is about requests-mock and JSON, explicitly.

From the [requests-mock docs](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/response.html#response-lists) it says:

> Multiple responses can be provided to be returned in order by specifying the keyword parameters in a list. If the list is exhausted then the last response will continue to be returned.

The example uses the adapter style:

```py
adapter.register_uri('GET', 'mock://test.com/4', [{'text': 'resp1', 'status_code': 300},
                                                  {'text': 'resp2', 'status_code': 200}])
```

What threw me off was that you have to call `'json'` as the key, in the list of dictionary responses.

In the case of JSON, you'd do the following for your code:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def mock_response(requests_mock):
    test_url = "https://dummy/"
    # assuming you want the first time to return 'TheName' 
    # and the 2nd time to return 'TheOtherName'
    requests_mock.get(
        test_url, 
        [
            {'json': {"Name": "TheName"}, 'status_code': 200},
            {'json': {"Name": "TheOtherName"}, 'status_code': 200}
        ]
    )
    resp = requests.get(test_url)
    return resp
```