# How to parametrize fixture before some test?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing

```py
from pytest import fixture

@fixture
def env():
    return {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}


def do_work(env):
    print("working")


def test_0(env):
    do_work(env)


def test_1(env):
    env["key1"] = "new_value1"

    do_work(env)


def test_2(env):
    env["key2"] = "new_value3"

    do_work(env)
```

In example I have `test_1` and `test_2` that do the same `do_work`, but before calling it edit fixture. How can I use parametrization (or anything else) to avoid writing two tests?
I can't just use `fixture parametrization` as is because `test_0` does not require parametrization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions), also check [How to parametrize a Pytest fixture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228895/how-to-parametrize-a-pytest-fixture):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("key, value", (
        ("key1", "new_value1"),
        ("key2", "new_value2")
))
def test_1(env, key, value):
    env[key] = value

    do_work(env)
```