# Passing arguments to instantiate object in Pytest

Tags: pytest

I have a class which I would like to instantiate using different sets of input parameters, comparing a property on the resultant object to a passed in value.

I am using the indirect flag on @pytest.fixture for the arguments which are sent to the class constructor. I am trying to unpack kwargs in the constructor. Unsuccesfully. This is the error:

TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not SubRequest

Code:

```
import pytest

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

@pytest.fixture
def my_object(request):
    yield MyClass(**request)

# first element = arguments to MyClass, second element = value to compare test to
TEST_CASES = [({"a":1}, 1)]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test, expected", TEST_CASES, indirect=["test"])
def test_1(my_object, test, expected):
    assert my_object.a == expected
```

My goal is to have the object arguments and their test value TEST_CASES in one structure for easy inspection

Comment: Two issues: 1. `my_object` has to be named `test` in order for indirect parametrization to work and 2. `request` is a fixture, not test parameters. Access them via `request.param`.

Comment: Perfect. Let's say I have MyClass2 and I need to pass that object in to the test as well. Case (1) MyClass2 doesn't need to be parameterised and (2) It does....how do I make pytest do that?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you. I have raised a new question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52599849/passing-more-than-one-argument-to-instantiate-more-than-one-object-in-pytest)

Answer (score 0):

I've suggest you a working example. Problem was in test code design. The parameter `indirect` should be `True`. Indirect parametrization with multiple fixtures should be done as described in [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization-with-multiple-fixtures). And fixture got **all** params in his `request.param` attribute.

```py
import pytest


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a


@pytest.yield_fixture
def test_case(request):
    params, expected = request.param
    yield MyClass(**params), expected


# first element = arguments to MyClass, second element = value to compare test to
TEST_CASES = [({"a": 1}, 1)]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_case", TEST_CASES, indirect=True)
def test_1(test_case):
    my_object, expected = test_case
    assert my_object.a == expected
```

Comment: Thank you Sergey. I only want to pass some arguments to the object fixture, the other argument goes to the test. I went with hoefling's answer. I do have a further question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52599849/passing-more-than-one-argument-to-instantiate-more-than-one-object-in-pytest

Comment: You may also wish to have a look at "parameter fixture" instead of using `indirect`. It is a bit more elegant IMHO. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55394178/7262247