# py.test Parameterise a fixture function AND test function

Tags: python, pytest

Similar to this question: [py.test: Pass a parameter to a fixture function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/py-test-pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function), however, we want to also paramaterise inputs to the test.

For example (this is simplified version of what I want to do):

```
import pytest


def person_says(name, age):
    return f"{name} is {age}"


@pytest.fixture
def add_surname(request):
    surname = request.param
    return f'Mike {surname}'


NAME1 = "Johnson"
AGE1 = "13"
OUTPUT1 = "Mike Johnson is 13"
NAME2 = "Liam"
AGE2 = "21"
OUTPUT2 = "Mike Liam is 21"
```

I want to pass something like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('add_surname,age,expected',
                         [[NAME1, AGE1, OUTPUT1], 
                          [NAME2, AGE2, OUTPUT2]],
                         indirect=True)
def test_person_says(add_surname, age, expected):
    name = add_surname
    output = person_says(name, age)
    assert expected == output
```

But that doesn't work, as it looks for the fixture `age`, which doesn't exist.

---

Using multiple decorators does all 4 combinations.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('age,expected', [[AGE1, OUTPUT1], [AGE2, OUTPUT2]])
@pytest.mark.parametrize('add_surname', [NAME1, NAME2], indirect=True)
def test_person_says(add_surname, age, expected):
    name = add_surname
    output = person_says(name, age)
    assert expected == output
```

Results:

```
Expected :Mike Liam is 21        Actual   :Mike Johnson is 21  # FAIL
Expected :Mike Johnson is 13     Actual   :Mike Johnson is 13  # Pass
Expected :Mike Johnson is 13     Actual   :Mike Liam is 13     # FAIL
Expected :Mike Liam is 21        Actual   :Mike Liam is 21     # Pass
```

What is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides of a boolean, `indirect` can take a list of input names, so indirect parametrization via fixtures is only applied to those inputs. Example:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('x, y, z', [('spam', 'eggs', 'bacon')], indirect=['x', 'y'])
```

`x` and `y` are parametrized indirectly, so `spam` and `eggs` will be passed through `x` and `y` fixtures, but `z` is parametrized directly, so `bacon` will be used as plain input. In your case:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('add_surname,age,expected',
                         [[NAME1, AGE1, OUTPUT1], 
                         [NAME2, AGE2, OUTPUT2]],
                         indirect=['add_surname'])
```

will do the trick.