# pytest - @parametrize - can i @parametrize a test using data GIVEN by a fixture?

Tags: pytest, fixtures

using python 3.8 and pytest 5.3.2

in conftest.py i have a fixture that read data from a json configuration file,
in order to reuse data read from the json configuration file in a several test.

## configuration.json

```
{"username":"user", "endpoints":["https://www.something.com/url1", "https://www.something.com/url2"]}
```

## conftest.py

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--configuration", action="store", default="configuration.json")


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def configuration(request):
    configuration= None
    configuration= request.config.getoption("--configuration")
    with open(configuration, 'r') as f:
        configuration= json.load(f)
    return configuration
```

and this works fine :

```
class TestService():
   def test_something(configuration)
      assert configuration['username'] == 'user'
```

in this case the test read data from configuration fixture that read data from configuration.json file.

the problem is when i want to use this data with [@parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) :

i want to convert this approach:

```
@mark.parametrize('endpoint', [
    "https://www.something.com/url1", "https://www.something.com/url2"
])
def test_endpoints_parametrizzato(endpoint):
    print(endpoint)
    assert requests.get(endpoint).status_code == 200
```

with this approach

```
@mark.parametrize('endpoint', configuration['endpoints'])
def test_endpoints_parametrizzato(endpoint):
    print(endpoint)
    assert requests.get(endpoint).status_code == 200
```

but this will not work because @parametrize will not "see" the fixture i want to use to parametrize it. i read a lot of articles but i'm not able to understand if i'm doing something wrong or i cannot parametrize reading data from a fixture. can someone help me explaining again? i read

- https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349
- https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/proposals/parametrize_with_fixtures.html
- [Pass a parameter to a fixture function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function)

Answer (score 1):

as discussed [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/6374) you can't.

you can use [a custom test generator](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#basic-pytest-generate-tests-example)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a fixture to pass as parametrize argument you can write a function and call it.

```
def get_configuration(key):
    with open("configuration.json", 'r') as f:
        configuration = json.load(f)
    return configuration.get('key')

    @mark.parametrize('endpoint', get_configuration('endpoints'))
def test_endpoints_parametrizzato(endpoint):
    print(endpoint)
    assert requests.get(endpoint).status_code == 200
```