# Creating PyTest fixture parameters dynamically from another fixture

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have an AWS S3 directory containing several JSON files, which are used as test inputs.

I've created a PyTest module that downloads all JSON files once using a module wide `fixture`, and then runs several test functions - each being parameterized over the set of JSONs:

```py
import pytest
import os
from tempfile import mkdtemp, TemporaryDirectory
from glob import glob

JSONS_AWS_PATH = 's3://some/path/'

def download_jsons():
    temp_dir = mkdtemp()
    aws_sync_dir(JSONS_AWS_PATH, temp_dir)
    json_filenames = glob(os.path.join(local_path, "*.json"))
    return json_filenames

@pytest.fixture(scope='module', params=download_jsons()) #<-- Invoking download_jsons() directly
def json_file(request):
    return request.param

def test_something(json_file):
   # Open the json file and test something

def test_something_else(json_file):
   # Open the json file and test something else

def test_another_thing(json_file):
   # you got the point...
```

This test module in itself works - the only pain point is how to cleanup the `temp_dir` at the end of the module\session.
Since `download_jsons()` is being invoked directly, before `json_file` fixture is even started - it has no context of its own. So I can't make it clean `temp_dir` after all the tests are done.

I would like to make `download_jsons()` a module\session scope `fixture` in itself. Something like:

```py
fixture(scope='module')
def download_jsons():
   temp_dir = mkdtemp()
   # Download and as glob, as above
   yield json_filenames
   shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```

or

```py
fixture(scope='module')
def download_jsons(tmpdir_factory):
    #...
```

as @Gabriela Melo has suggested.

The question is how to make the `json_file` fixture parameterized over the list returned by `download_jsons()`, without invoking it directly?

I've tried implementing this solution with either [`mark.parametrize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function), [`setup_module()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html), or [`pytest_generate_tests(metafunc)`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.8.7/parametrize.html#the-metafunc-object) - but wasn't able to implement the exact functionality I was looking for.

Comment: Is your question about using fixtures as parametrization arguments? This is not supported, see [issue #349](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349). Or is it just about cleaning up a temp directory? This can be easily done in multiple ways, without needing to have the code in an extra fixture.

Comment: Thanks! I've missed that issue. Good to know that's not supported. My question is how to create the temp dir before the `json_load()` fixture is evaluated the first time, so it could be parameterized over the tempdir's content. Then I need to delete the tempdir after the **last** invocation of the fixture (it's being used several times by several test functions). I couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: This could go even beyond a single `module` - I might need to download the JSONs once per session, parametrize tests from different modules over the contents of the tempdir, then delete the dir when the session ends.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a resource for parametrization, it can't be returned by a fixture (at least with the current version of `pytest`). However, you can move the setup/teardown code out to the hooks - this will also enable parametrizing via `pytest_generate_tests` hook. Example: in the root dir of your project, create a file named `conftest.py` with the following contents:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
from pathlib import Path


def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    # this is where we create the temp dir and download the files
    session.config._tempdir = TemporaryDirectory()
    d = session.config._tempdir.name
    aws_sync_dir(JSONS_BLOBBY_PATH, d)
    session.config._json_files = Path(d).glob("*.json")


def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
    # this is where we delete the created temp dir
    session.config._tempdir.cleanup()


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if "file" in metafunc.fixturenames:
        # parametrize the file argument with the downloaded files
        files = metafunc.config._json_files
        metafunc.parametrize("file", files)
```

You can now use the `file` argument in tests as usual, e.g.

```
def test_ends_with_json(file):
    assert file.suffix == ".json"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you're looking for: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html#the-tmpdir-factory-fixture

(Using Pytest's `tmpdir_factory` fixture and setting the scope of your `json_file` function to `session` instead of `module`)

Comment: I've tried that as well - and it doesn't seem to be the right solution.
Since `json_file ` is being **parameterized** by `download_json()` - the code in `download_json()` runs before the fixture even starts. So I can't define the dir inside `json_file()` (even if it is session scope).
Moreover, per [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session) - if a fixture is being parametrized, it may run more than once, even if it is in `session` scope (I've added prints and verified that).

Comment: In essence - I need `download_json` to be a fixture in itself, so it could take `tmpdir_factory` as input - but then I couldn't find a way to make it the parametrizing function of `json_file`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It has helped me better phrase the question, which wasn't actually about `tempdir` creation but how to parametrize one fixture using another. I've edited the question accordingly.