# pytest fixture with argument

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

It seems it it possible to pass argument to fixtures:

[Pass a parameter to a fixture function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function)

yet, when implementing this minimal example, I get an error.

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture(v):
    print("fixture in")
    yield v+1
    print("fixture out")

@pytest.mark.parametrize("my_fixture",[1], indirect=True)
def test_myfixture(my_fixture):
    print(my_fixture)
```

> @pytest.fixture
> def my_fixture(v):
> E       fixture 'v' not found

Is anything wrong with the code above ?

(python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture(request):
    print("fixture in")
    yield request.param+1 # difference here !
    print("fixture out")

@pytest.mark.parametrize("my_fixture",[1], indirect=True)
def test_myfixture(my_fixture):
    print(my_fixture)
```

Comment: From the docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments

Comment: see also the answer from Kale Kundert for more details

Answer (score 7):

To briefly elaborate on Vince's answer: in general, arguments to fixture functions are interpreted as the names of other fixtures to load before the one being defined.  That's why you got the error message `fixture 'v' not found`: pytest thought that you wanted `my_fixture` to depend on another fixture called `v` that doesn't exist.

The `request` argument is an exception to this general rule.  It doesn't refer to another fixture.  Instead, it instructs pytest to give the fixture access to the `request` object, which contains information on the currently running test, e.g. which parameters are being tested (via `request.param`), which markers the test has (via `request.node.get_closest_marker()`), etc.

So to make use of indirect parametrization, your fixture needs to (i) accept the `request` argument and (ii) do something with `request.param`.  For more information, here are the relevant pages in the documentation:

- [The `request` argument](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#fixtures-can-introspect-the-requesting-test-context)
- [Parametrized fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/fixtures.html#parametrizing-fixtures)
- [Indirect parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong. Fixtures are used to fix constants to reuse them identically in multiple tests. They don't accept any argument. By the way you can create a pytest.fixture that is a "constant" function:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def my_fixture():
    return lambda x: x+1
```

And avoid `print` in fixture (on the final version at least).