# Difference between `scope` in `fixture` and `scope` in `parametrize` when using indirect parametrization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures, parametrized-testing

I want to use indirect parametrization as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33879151/8896457) and in [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments).

I want to be able to set scope to be able to configure if fixture is run for every function or once for many of them.

However I see that I can set scope on `fixture` decorator:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def fixt(request):
    return request.param * 3

@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixt", ["a", "b"], indirect=True)
def test_indirect(fixt):
    assert len(fixt) == 3
```

Or on `parametrize` decorator:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def fixt(request):
    return request.param * 3

@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixt", ["a", "b"], indirect=True, scope="function")
def test_indirect(fixt):
    assert len(fixt) == 3
```

Or even both at the same time:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def fixt(request):
    return request.param * 3

@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixt", ["a", "b"], indirect=True, scope="function")
def test_indirect(fixt):
    assert len(fixt) == 3
```

What is the difference and when I should set each?

---

Update:

I tested each to see how they differ.

Code I used for testing:

```
import pytest

scope_fixture="function"
scope_parametrize="module"

with open('scope_log.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(f'--------\n')
    file.write(f'{scope_fixture=}\n')
    file.write(f'{scope_parametrize=}\n')

@pytest.fixture(scope=scope_fixture)
def fixt(request):
    with open('scope_log.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(f'fixture ' + str(request.param)+'\n')
    return request.param * 3

@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixt", ["a", "b"], indirect=True, scope=scope_parametrize)
def test_indirect1(fixt):
    with open('scope_log.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(f'1 ' + str(fixt)+'\n')
    assert len(fixt) == 3

@pytest.mark.parametrize("fixt", ["a", "b"], indirect=True, scope=scope_parametrize)
def test_indirect2(fixt):
    with open('scope_log.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(f'2 ' + str(fixt)+'\n')
    assert len(fixt) == 3
```

Results:

```
scope_fixture=None
scope_parametrize=None
fixture a
1 aaa
fixture b
1 bbb
fixture a
2 aaa
fixture b
2 bbb
--------
scope_fixture='function'
scope_parametrize=None
fixture a
1 aaa
fixture b
1 bbb
fixture a
2 aaa
fixture b
2 bbb
--------
scope_fixture='module'
scope_parametrize=None
fixture a
1 aaa
2 aaa
fixture b
1 bbb
2 bbb
--------
scope_fixture=None
scope_parametrize='function'
fixture a
1 aaa
fixture b
1 bbb
fixture a
2 aaa
fixture b
2 bbb
--------
scope_fixture=None
scope_parametrize='module'
fixture a
1 aaa
2 aaa
fixture b
1 bbb
2 bbb
--------
scope_fixture='function'
scope_parametrize='module'
fixture a
1 aaa
2 aaa
fixture b
1 bbb
2 bbb
--------
scope_fixture='module'
scope_parametrize='module'
fixture a
1 aaa
2 aaa
fixture b
1 bbb
2 bbb
--------
scope_fixture='module'
scope_parametrize='function'
fixture a
1 aaa
fixture b
1 bbb
fixture a
2 aaa
fixture b
2 bbb
--------
scope_fixture='function'
scope_parametrize='function'
fixture a
1 aaa
fixture b
1 bbb
fixture a
2 aaa
fixture b
2 bbb
```

Comment: Did you try using each? Could you observe a difference in what tests occurred (or, for that matter, how many)?

Comment: Setting the scope for `parametrize´ [overrides any scope set in fixtures.](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.Metafunc.parametrize) I would only set the scope if I have to, one example could be the case of reading input from a file and I only want to do it once to save time with I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tzane pointed out in comment, setting the scope for `parametrize` overrides any scope set in fixtures.

From [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.Metafunc.parametrize):

> scope (Optional[_ScopeName]) – If specified it denotes the scope of
> the parameters. The scope is used for grouping tests by parameter
> instances. **It will also override any fixture-function defined scope**,
> allowing to set a dynamic scope using test context or configuration.