# Can't pass argument to fixture indirectly

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I can't get the indirect fixture argument pass right:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def sorted_array(to_power):
    assert to_power.param >= 2
    size = int(math.pow(2, to_power.param))
    array = [i for i in range(size)]
    return array


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "sorted_array",
    [(2)],
    indirect=["sorted_array"],
)
def test_binary_search_2(sorted_array):
    times_elapsed = []
    ...
```

I've read [Pass a parameter to a fixture function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function) and [the official documentation ont the topic](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#apply-indirect-on-particular-arguments). My code seems to follow the advice in those documents and yet, when trying to run the tests copied above I get:

```
test setup failed
file /Users/mwasilewski/Code/algorithms/python/tests/test_binary_search.py, line 38
  @pytest.mark.parametrize(
      "sorted_array",
      [(2)],
      indirect=["sorted_array"],
  )
  def test_binary_search_2(sorted_array):
file /Users/mwasilewski/Code/algorithms/python/tests/test_binary_search.py, line 30
  @pytest.fixture(scope="function")
  def sorted_array(to_power):
E       fixture 'to_power' not found
```

I am puzzled and any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` is not a usual parameter, it's a [SubRequest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/_modules/_pytest/fixtures.html) that is used for handling getting a fixture from a test function or another [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html). If you change it to any other variable, `to_power` for example, `pytest` will look for another fixture with that name. In addition the `indirect` should be a boolean `True`, not a list

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def sorted_array(request):
    assert request.param >= 2
    size = int(math.pow(2, request.param))
    array = [i for i in range(size)]
    return array


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "sorted_array",
    [2],
    indirect=True
)
def test_binary_search_2(sorted_array):
    print(sorted_array) # [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you.